# REST entity id in PATCH request body

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I've got a `FooEnity` with an id of 35 exposed by a web service, and it is located at at `/myhost/api/fooentity/35`.

Now I want to implement a PATCH call to allow partial updates to `FooEntity` (so let's say 2 of the 25 available fields are passed up to be updated).

My question is, should the PATCH content (json/xml) include the `id` of 35?  The address of the entity is specified by the URI, and `id` is not an updateable field, and if it was included it is an extra validation to make sure both ids match.  All of this suggests **No**.  Still, it feels weird not having it in there.

What is the appropriate way to do this?

(Note, question is language independent, but is implemented in the ASP.NET 4.0 Web API framework, if that influences anyone's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great question!

There are two ways you can handle that. You can either raise a validation error if the id in the body is different from the id in the URI. Or you can just ignore whatever id is in the request body. If you're patching by manually copying properties, you would just not copy the id property to ignore it. If you're using a helper class to patch the entity, you could apply the patch and then set the entity's id to be whatever came in on the URI just to make sure that it keeps the same id after the patch.

Whichever option you pick is really up to you. Sending back a 400 if the request body id doesn't match the entity id might be a little clearer for clients so they understand that the id won't be changed, but it also requires you to write more code to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Given everything I've laid out, and your own list of options, which way would you do it?

Comment: Personally, I would just ignore the ID in the request body. I'm not claiming that's the best solution, but I like keeping my logic as simple as possible, within reason.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I ended up making the id field a nullable int  (and therefore optional) in the model for the PATCH method and swapping in the id from the URI if the model.id was null.  If specified and different than the one in the URI though, I returned a Bad Request.